# Left align columns in data frame

Tags: r

I would like to print a data frame where all columns are left aligned. The following code doesn’t produce the expected result because the last column is right aligned.

Here is the code:

```
tab <- data.frame(x = rep("Multi", 7), y = c("BC", "AB", "ABCD", "AER", "A", "A", "OI"), z = c(0.533, 10.658, 0.317, 4, 2000, 0.478, 1.569))

tab$y <- as.character(tab$y)
for(i in 1:dim(tab)[1]){
tab[i,c("y")] <- paste0('"', paste(tab[i,c("y")], collapse="\", \""), '"')
}

tab_format <- apply(tab, 2, format)
write.table(tab_format, file = "test1.txt", sep = " ", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

Produced output

```
Multi "BC"      0.533
Multi "AB"     10.658
Multi "ABCD"    0.317
Multi "AER"     4.000
Multi "A"    2000.000
Multi "A"       0.478
Multi "OI"      1.569
```

Expected output

```
Multi "BC"   0.533
Multi "AB"   10.658
Multi "ABCD" 0.317
Multi "AER"  4
Multi "A"    2000
Multi "A"    0.478
Multi "OI"   1.569
```

Comment: Can you explain more about why you want the numbers left justified (and not with decimal places aligned), for example is this for a report on the screen or a table that you would like to format in HTML or PDF/word? Thanks.

Comment: This is for a table that I would like to format in .txt. Next, the file .txt  is used for another software.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `pander` package you can do something like this (`ca_data` is a test data frame I have left over from another problem):

```
> library(pander)
> ca_data
            dim1       dim2
text1  1.2143543 -4.3103880
text2 -0.1647548  2.3744269
text3  0.3792852 -0.2677051
text4  0.8941859  0.1106750
text5 -1.5283987 -0.3439418

> panderOptions('table.alignment.default',function(df) ifelse(sapply(df, is.numeric), 'left'))
```

This provides:

```
 > pander(ca_data)

-------------------------------
  &nbsp;    dim1      dim2     
----------- --------- ---------
 **text1**  1.214     -4.31    
 **text2**  -0.1648   2.374    
 **text3**  0.3793    -0.2677  
 **text4**  0.8942    0.1107   
 **text5**  -1.528    -0.3439  
-------------------------------
```

Comment: If you can edit your question to provide more info about the context of the problem a better solution can be found. There is no code for where or how your `write.table` is failing in the question above. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I've tried to write the data in write.table but this doesn't work when I use pander (). The file .txt is empty.